# JMeter - load balancing

Tags: jboss, jmeter

In our application, We have 6 instance of application server.

When we test it manually, we will land on some node randomly.
When i run our JMeter test (with 20 users), most of the load(70%) goes to 1 specific node out of 6 nodes. 
30% goes to another specific node from the rest 5.

I see the information via JSESSIONID set in the request cookies.

**Issue**:

I was thinking the load will be balanced on all the 6 nodes equally (more or less).
Is this my application issue? Or Does it have to do anything with JMeter?

**Note:**

- Our app server is JBoss. It is a cookie injection based load balancing.
- I do not send the request to any specific app server via cookie. The cookie is set automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure that [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) is added to your test plan, it should be enough to automatically resolve cookie-based load balancing problem.

If you have > 1 load balancer instance or the load balancer resolves in > 1 IP address you may have to add a [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) as well. See [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) guide for better explanation and configuration details.

Comment: I already have cookie manager. But with 20 users, I could not see the requests coming to other nodes. When i increase the load, other nodes get some requests. Looks like i did not have enough load to test that.  Thanks for sharing some new information on DNS Cache manager... But as per the other other answer, "so all requests coming form the Jmeter server go to the same target"   --> is this true?

Comment: If your load balancer orchestrates the load basing on source IP address you will need to configure JMeter for [IP spoofing](http://blog.milamberspace.net/index.php/2009/12/03/changer-ladresse-ip-source-dune-requete-http-lors-dun-test-avec-jmeter-549.html) (the post is in French however you should be able to use online translation tools or look into images to get the idea - it can be understood)

Answer (score 2):

Beside what Dmitri suggested you should check the way your LB is configured.

In many cases, the LB distributes the requests based on source IP, so all requests coming form the Jmeter server go to the same target.
This happens especially when the LB does not terminate the https traffic.